# coinbase-api python API get_accounts() is not getting all positions

Tags: coinbase-api

The result is missing my MKR balance.  It returns my other positions but not MKR.  I confirmed I have a non-zero balance on website.  Why does this happen only with MKR?

```
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client
client = Client('key', 'secret')
print(client.get_accounts())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
print(client.get_accounts(limit=100))
```

Comment: omg that actually worked.  WHY THOUGH?  I only saw your reply today.